# Read KML file with GDAL/OGR and access all its attributes

Tags: python, gdal, kml, ogr

I have a KML file and I'm trying to access a specific attribute named "styleUrl".

A feature of this KML looks like this:

```
<Placemark>
  <name/>
  <styleUrl>BoundaryStyle</styleUrl>
  <ExtendedData>
    <Data name="MapType">
      <value>5</value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="GisRefAlt">
      <value>147.243</value>
    </Data>
  </ExtendedData>
  <LineString>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
    <coordinates>
      1.933319193,48.85467984,0
      1.933486465,48.855114809,0
      1.93348817599999,48.855122366,0
      1.93349044799999,48.855131881,0
    </coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

I tried to do this, but It seems like ogr doesn't keep all attributes from the original file.

```
from osgeo import ogr


driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('KML')
dataSource = driver.Open('DEFONCE_Original.kml', 0)


for lid in range(dataSource.GetLayerCount()):
    layer = dataSource.GetLayerByIndex(lid)


    for feature in layer:
        style_url = feature.GetFieldAsString('styleUrl')


        print("Layer:", layer.GetName())
        print("Style URL:", style_url)
```

Do you know if I can retrieve the "styleUrl" attribute of the feature with ogr ?

Comment: Have you tried to use LIBKML driver?

Comment: @user30184 Yes, same problem.

Comment: See how GDAL is handling styles  and Style URL in the driver autotests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_libkml.py. It may be that GDAL does not consider Style URL as a normal attribute.